# DB2 to SQL Server migration: The conversion of cursors in return statements is not supported

Tags: sql-server, db2, database-migration, mssql-jdbc, database-optimization

We are converting DB2 procs over to SQL Server using the Microsoft SQL server migration assistant, and getting below error in the generated SQL Server proc:

> Errors:DB22SS0245 The conversion of cursors in return statements is not supported

DB2 proc(omitting create syntax and actual complex logic):

```
BEGIN 
 DECLARE temp_cursor CURSOR WITH HOLD WITH RETURN TO CALLER
  FOR SELECT * FROM EMP
  FOR READ ONLY;
  OPEN temp_cursor;
 END
```

How do I convert this to its SQL Server equivalent with the minimum amount of change? The possible solution I have read here suggest quite drastic changes to the proc, which is difficult for us since the procs are huge and many in number. Thank you!

Comment: For anything like this you will have to find the equivalent way to do it in SQL Server - and anything that is non ANSI standard SQL will potentially require quite a bit of change, even to the level of complete re-write as each database supports quite different functionality. I expect it will be a slow process requiring the documentation for each product.

Comment: _minimum amount of change_ A fool's paradise and a contractor's dream. That is never the "best" way to migrate as that avoids the difficult work of designing a database and writing code that is efficient for the underlying database engine.

Comment: In SQL Server stored procedures can only return `int` values as their return status. You could still declare an `@CursorName cursor output` parameter, though, and initialize it with something like `set @CursorName=cursor for select foo from dbo.Bar where Baz = 1`

Comment: Yes there is a `RETURN 0` at the end of the proc, ignored for brevity. This did not work for me and am getting the same error @AlwaysLearning

Comment: Better question: why do you want a cursor in the first place, they are rareely the right solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting what worked for me. As the proc was just returning a select statement, the use of cursor does not add any advantage in this use case. Refactored the proc without cursor, and with just the select statment.

```
BEGIN 
 SELECT * FROM EMP
 RETURN 0
END
```